# Removing a dropdown that keeps moving

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu

I am trying to clean up an excel file, by checking in the selection pane if there are any hidden shapes left. Several sheets show that there is a drop down hidden. When I click show all it will show the drop down on the current active cell, but I can't seem to remove it. When I click on a different cell, the hidden dropdown will have moved there when I click show all again.
Any ideas on how to get rid of this?

Comment: no one knows I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unsure what was causing this. In the end rebooting the PC did the trick...